# Dynamically added modals aren't triggering

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I am loading cards and there modals dynamically and the problem I am facing is that the dynamically added cards aren't triggering the dynamically added modals.
The cards  are this

```
data.forEach(eve => {
         console.log(eve.data());
         event = eve.data();
         pastEventCards+=`
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card_image">
                    <img src="images/posters/cpp_2021.jpeg" />
                </div>
                <div class="card_content card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <h2 class="card_title">${event.title}</h2>
                    <p class="card_text">

                    </p>
                    **<button data-modal-trigger="past-event-modal-${event.eventNo}" class="mt-auto demo__btn demo__btn--secondary">
                        Read More
                    </button>**
                </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         `
        pastEventModals+=`
        <div class="modal" data-modal-name="past-event-modal-${event.eventNo}">
        <div class="modal__dialog">
            <button class="modal__close" data-modal-dismiss>×</button>
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title">${event.title}</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <h4 class="modal_description">Description</h4>
                </p>
                <p>${event.description}</p>
                <p class="modal_description">
                    ${event.date}
                </p>
                <p class="modal_description">Attendees : ${event.attendee}
                </p>
                <p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-modal-dismiss>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
     });

    cardsList.innerHTML = pastEventCards ;
    modalList.innerHTML = pastEventModals ;
```

I have tried referring to other stack overflow questions related to this and couldnt find a understandable solution to why this is happening , can anyone tell why the buttons cant trigger the modals ?

**EDIT :: **

The button that triggers the modal is inside this  ** ** in the pastEventCards variable and the modal is in pastEventModals and when i use  "data-modal-trigger = "something" " it will trigger the modal with modal name "something" right ? So y isnt it happening. If I dont add this modals and trigger cards dynamically and add it in the html template then it works fine but after adding dynamically it doesnt work

Comment: Where's the code that actually shows the modal? Is it bound to the button with an event listener? If so, you'll have to rebind that event listener after you add new cards to the DOM.